# Trigger a script when a file is moved in a folder (Linux)

Tags: bash, file, triggers, hook, move

What's the best way to trigger a bash script automatically when a file is moved in a folder ? (I'm working in a Linux environment)

I don't want to use a cron job that checks every minutes my folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692353/executing-a-bash-script-upon-file-creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inotify-tools or fileschanged. These programs can be used to monitor and act upon filesystem events.

```
https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki

http://fileschanged.sourceforge.net/
```