# Automatically copy Java heapdump from Kubernetes to s3

Tags: java, kubernetes, amazon-s3, heap-dump

We have running Java applications inside Kubernetes pods. In case of Java OOM heap dump generated on the local pod's storage, I want to automatically copy heapdump to s3, before pod restart or k8s tigger liveness.
Now there are multiple possibilities to copy heapdump to s3 automatically.

1. Install AWS cli and 3rdparty tools([inotifywait](https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes), [incron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692353/executing-a-bash-script-upon-file-creation)) and copy automatically on s3.
2. Mount S3 drive on Kubernetes pod, i personally discourage it as it requires infrastructure change.
3. Is there any way inside Kubernetes that can copy heapdump directly on s3, without installing any 3rth party tool or mounting drive on pod

OR what are your recommendations?